# I can not backup my database in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

plz help me
i develop one app with Django and my database in the PostgreSQL
my database name is company and have many data
one month ago i can backup but now! PostgreSQL not allow to backup

i decided to create one roll for backup automatically, but again alert to me that problem

Comment: That belongs to DBA Stackexchange, but not in its current form. You need to add more information.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome! Maybe it will help you.

PostgreSQL incorporates a utility called "pg_dump" that can be utilized to dump database data into a record for reinforcement purposes.

`pg_dump name_of_database > name_of_backup_file`

**!The command must be run by a user with privileges to read all of the database information!**

Hope that helps you